# Can a predicate be a contradiction?

Tags: logic

In the university course I'm taking, a predicate is defined as a mathematical statement whose truth value depends on the variables involved in the statement. This definition makes me wonder whether a predicate can be a contradiction.

For instance, if we use $P(x)$ to denote the statement "$x$ is an even number", clearly $P(x)$ itself is a predicate.

However, if we consider the statement

> $x$ is an even number and $x$ is not an even number,

it can be written as $P(x)\land\lnot P(x)$.

I think based on my knowledge it is a valid statement, but I am not sure whether it is a predicate. The part I am not sure about is:

1. By the law of excluded middle and well-definedness of mathematical statements, the statement should always be false regardless of the value of $x$. Hence, without knowing the value of $x$, we can say that this statement is false. In this sense, the truth value of this statement does not depend on the value of $x$, so it should not be a predicate.
2. However, I feel in the above argument (1), I unconsciously use $\forall$ to quantifier the statement, which makes it a proposition (or at least we can directly tell the truth value without considering $x$). If this is true, this statement should be a predicate.

I feel I could not figure out which of my thoughts is true, or both of them are wrong, could someone please help me on this?

Comment: I would say that a "predicate" is expressed by a *predicate symbol* $P(x)$. A formula with a free variable $\varphi(x)$ expresses a "property".

Comment: If we follow this approach, we may have the formula $\varphi(x) := Px \land \lnot Px$ that "defines" the "empty" property, i.e. the property whose extension is the empty set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$P(x)\land\lnot P(x).$$
>
> I think based on my knowledge it is a valid statement,
> but I am not sure whether it is a predicate.

By **definition**, a predicate is a formula with a free variable.

$P(x)$ is typically understood to mean something like $$∃y\;x=2y,$$ but not $$∃x\;x=2x.$$ In other words, *by convention*, $P(x)\land\lnot P(x)$ ***does*** indicate a predicate.

> I think based on my knowledge it is a **valid statement**

A statement typically means a formula with no free variable; the given formula is a “well-formed formula” rather than a statement.

It is clearly a contradiction—i.e., its truth-functional form is false regardless of interpretation—so cannot be valid—i.e., true regardless of interpretation—either.

In general, some predicates are [unsatisfiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512153/21813)—false regardless of interpretation—[some predicates are valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4313712/21813)—true regardless of interpretation—some predicates are satisfiable but invalid.

> 1. By the law of excluded middle and well-definedness of mathematical
>    statements, the statement should always be false regardless of the
>    value of $x$. Hence, without knowing the value of $x$, we can say that
>    this statement is false. In this sense, the truth value of this
>    statement does not depend on the value of $x$, so it should not be a
>    predicate.
> 2. However, I feel in the above argument (1), I unconsciously use
>    $\forall$ to quantifier the statement, which makes it a proposition
>    (or at least we can directly tell the truth value without considering
>    $x$). If this is true, this statement should be a predicate.

This is unsound reasoning, based on the *misconception* that a predicate's truth value is necessarily dependent on its free variable. (Compare this characterisation with the definition in the first line.)

The fact that the given formula *remains* true upon quantification does not negate the fact that it is a predicate.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. But just to clarify myself, the word 'valid' was meant to indicate that I thought the sentence is indeed a statement, rather than the truth value of this statement.

Comment: @Doero I knew what you meant, and was highlighting that the technical meaning of 'valid' means that we have to be careful about using it in the layman sense. I occasionally make this slip too.

Comment: And also, from your response, I felt you made a distinction between statement and well-formed formula, is there a difference between them? From the construction of wff I feel they are the same in some sense.

Comment: I see! Thanks for point this out.

Comment: @Doero Every statement (no free variable) is a formula (can have a free variable), but not vice versa.

Comment: @Doero P.S. When I find myself wanting to use 'valid' in a sense that contradicts its formal-logic meaning, I frequently say 'legit' instead.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 3):

We can, with no problems whatsoever, define a unary predicate symbol $Q$, which is defined such that $Q(x)$ is equivalent to the statement "$x$ is even *and* $x$ is not even". And, as you've noted, this is the same as the statement $\lnot T$, i.e. it is a statement that is false regardless of the value of $x$, meaning that the formula $\forall x \lnot Q(x)$ is a true sentence.

This is fine, and it is analogous to the fact that we can define a constant function, i.e. $f(x) = c$. $f$ is a function, it operates on $x$, but the operation it performs gives the same result regardless of $x$, but we would still say that $f$ is a function *of* $x$.

Importantly, we would definitely regard $Q$ as being a predicate, and hence dependent (if somewhat vacuously) on $x$, so $Q(x)$ is *not* a sentence as it has a free variable.

To think of it another way, consider that a lot of the time we take a predicate that we *think* is true for all of its inputs, and then try to prove it as such. If we have a predicate $P(x)$ and are trying to prove $\forall x P(x)$, how could $P$ suddenly become a different type of object depending on whether we succeed or not?

Comment: Thanks! The analogy to constant function is really helpful!